# Trouble connecting to MySQL through Node.js/Express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have a simple web hosting account, and I recently upgraded to enable Node.JS on my server. I have no problem connecting to MySQL with PHP, and performing queries. But I'm trying to build a small app with Node.js, and connecting to MySQL seems impossible. Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong? The Node instance seems to just consistently run a script path. It gives me the port of 26515 to use, and I've been able to use this port if I run a smaller program.

> ```
> Restarting /home/www/tannerbabcock.com/app/sql.js.
> { Error: connect EACCES 127.0.0.1:3306 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)
>     at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
>     at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
>     at internalConnect (net.js:960:16)
>     at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (internal/async_hooks.js:284:19)
>     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.emitLookup [as callback] (net.js:1106:9)
>     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:97:10)
>     --------------------
>     at Protocol._enqueue (/home/www/tannerbabcock.com/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
>     at Protocol.handshake (/home/www/tannerbabcock.com/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
>     at Connection.connect (/home/www/tannerbabcock.com/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:118:18)
>     at app.get (/home/www/tannerbabcock.com/app/sql.js:15:13)
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/www/tannerbabcock.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>     at next (/home/www/tannerbabcock.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
>     at Route.dispatch (/home/www/tannerbabcock.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/www/tannerbabcock.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>     at /home/www/tannerbabcock.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
>     at Function.process_params (/home/www/tannerbabcock.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
> code: 'EACCES',
> errno: 'EACCES',
> syscall: 'connect',
> address: '127.0.0.1',
> port: 3306,
> fatal: true }
> ```

Here is my code. The `node_modules` is not in the same directory as this file (`/home/www/tannerbabcock.com/app/sql.js`), but it's in the parent directory (`/home/www/tannerbabcock.com/node_modules`). I just want this program to output the contents of my "blog" table.

```
var express = require("express"),
    mysql = require("mysql");
    app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "my_username",
    password: "my_password",
    database: "my_database"
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    connection.connect((err, conn) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
    });

    connection.query("SELECT * FROM `blog`", (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err.message);
        }
        res.write("<html><head><title>Node.js App</title></head><body><table><tbody>");
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            res.write("<tr><td>" + rows[i].id + "</td><td>" + rows[i].title + "</td><td>" + rows[i].body + "</td><td>" + rows[i].tag + "</td><td>" + rows[i].comp + "</td></tr>");
        }
        res.end("</tbody></table></body></html>");
    });

    connection.end();
});

var server = app.listen(26515, "198.23.49.48");
```

I've been following along with the MySQL Node.js examples, but none of them really seem to help me.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the asyncrony. You are sending the query without getting the connection. The connection is retrieved in the callback of the connect. Out of that method you don't have the connection yet.

Something like this could work:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }

  connection.query("SELECT * FROM `blog`", (err, rows, fields) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
    }
        res.write("<html><head><title>Node.js App</title></head><body><table><tbody>");
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            res.write("<tr><td>" + rows[i].id + "</td><td>" + rows[i].title + "</td><td>" + rows[i].body + "</td><td>" + rows[i].tag + "</td><td>" + rows[i].comp + "</td></tr>");
        }
        res.end("</tbody></table></body></html>");
    });

    connection.end();

  });
});

var server = app.listen(26515, "198.23.49.48");
```